# ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2 compatibility with ASP Classic Project

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I want to use ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2 in a ASP Classic Project. Is it compatible?

Is there any another library that i can use with ASP Classic ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that ITfoxtec Identity SAML 2.0 du not support Classic ASP.

The only component that I think possible could support Classic ASP is Bouncy Castle.